# Netbeans 8.2 build successful but no output

Tags: java, netbeans

I recently installed Netbeans 8.2 with JDK 8 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit OS. Started the installation with jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe, which was successful. After that tried to install netbeans-8.2-javase-windows.exe, which gave me error stating could not find JDK. After searching over the internet I could get Netbeans to install from command prompt with netbeans-8.2-javase-windows.exe --jdkhome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131", Netbeans8.2 installation was successful.
Wrote a simple helloapp program: 
package helloapp;

```
public class Helloapp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("hello");
}

}
```

When I run this project by any means Run Main project, F6, right click run file gives me output as :

run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds).

I have worked with previous version 8.1, and have never had problem. Wonder what is missing here. Can someone tell me what I might be missing here.

Comment: You may want to be a little clearer as to what you are expecting to happen. And what is the value of %JAVA_HOME%?

Comment: I am expecting "hello" to be printed to output. I am sorry how do i check %JAVA_HOME%  ?

Comment: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in a Windows Command Prompt window.

Comment: c:\windows\system32> echo %JAVA_HOME%  gives  %JAVA_HOME%. Is that ok , or is there something wrong?

Comment: Java uses the JAVA_HOME environment variable to figure out where all its component bits are. It may be that Netbeans, with the `--jdkhome` flag, has that all sorted out (I'm no Netbeans expert); however I find things generally work better with JAVA_HOME properly set. So set the variable (Windows Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables); the result of `echo %JAVA_HOME%` should print out `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

Comment: (Windows Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables) under System variables, what should be the variable & value? . Should the Variable be JAVA_HOME & value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131 ? Should it point to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131 or C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin ?

Comment: Yes, variable `JAVA_HOME`, value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`, exactly. Not the `bin` directory.

Comment: The echo %JAVA_HOME% looks as expected but still i don't get output. IF i run the JAR file i get output but from Netbeans IDE nothing.

Comment: Ok, well, here's where I bow out. Somebody who actually knows NetBeans is going to have to help you on this. I can only offer two solutions: 1) re-install 8.2 or 2) go back to 8.1.

Comment: From [this similar but unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087346/why-does-this-code-returns-after-build-run-with-netbeans-8-2-run-build-succ?rq=1): "Are you sure the code gets executed? Maybe you have a second main method in your project which returns immediately. You can check in your project properties (right click on the project / properties) under "Run / Main Class" which main class will be executed when you run your project."

Comment: I have actually re-installed it twice already. I just have a single main method.  To re-check that it is executing main file i even put break point and ran in debugger mode , so it does run the file with no output, so strange.

Comment: try to run `Helloapp` by right click  `Helloapp.java` in project window other than pressing F6

Comment: tried that too it does not work.

Comment: try to clean the project first and then try to run it

Comment: tried that too it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make Sure that the class is not in the "default package".  It should lie in the project's package.
2. main method should be having the correct lines which are to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the class and add it to the classpath. Usually you should be able to Right-Click and then Run as...